# Count/Dense_rank agrupado sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, count

Estou tentando agrupar as linhas por grupo no *sqlserver* e como resultado quero:

> ```
> CICLO | CODFIL | CODITPROD | ROW
> 1     |   1    |     10    | 1
> 11    |   1    |     10    | 2
> 12    |   1    |     10    | 3
> 1     |   2    |     10    | 1
> 11    |   2    |     10    | 2
> 1     |   3    |     11    | 1
> 11    |   3    |     11    | 2
> ```

Porém a minha *query* me retorna

> ```
> CICLO | CODFIL | CODITPROD | ROW
> 1     |   1    |     10    | 1
> 11    |   1    |     10    | 1
> 12    |   1    |     10    | 1
> 1     |   2    |     10    | 1
> 11    |   2    |     10    | 1
> 1     |   3    |     11    | 1
> 11    |   3    |     11    | 1
> ```

Segue minha query

```
SELECT CICLO,
    CODFIL,
    CODITPROD,
    DENSE_RANK ()
    OVER (PARTITION BY CODFIL, CODITPROD
        ORDER BY CODFIL, CODITPROD )
    AS ROW
FROM TABELA R WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está utilizando `SQL Server` como indica a sua pergunta, provavelmente a função que você quer usar é a `ROW_NUMBER` e não `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT CICLO,
       CODFIL,
       CODITPROD,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODFIL, CODITPROD
                              ORDER BY CODFIL, CODITPROD ) AS ROW
  FROM TABELA R WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Confira o resultado no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68a1c/2)

---

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, iniciando em 1 para a primeira linha de cada partição.
>
> ```
> Aplica-se a: SQL Server (do SQL Server 2008 à versão atual), Banco de dados SQL do Windows Azure (da versão inicial até a versão atual).
> ```

Comment: Apenas pra conhecimento geral, o dense_rank é do sqlserver https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017... porem neste caso o row_count atende melhor, obrigado :D